# What's the table name for sales/order_payment?

Tags: php, magento, phpmyadmin

I have the Unirgy Dropship Module and am running Magento 1.3

Does anybody know the true table name which contains the data for an instance of `Mage::getModel('sales/order_payment')`?

I've seen in some places that it is `sales_flat_order_payment`, but this table doesn't exist in my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isn`t it sales_order?

check this schema

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-mysql-database-structure/

its a little bit old but so is 1.3.2

Hope it helps

Comment: If you look at the `eav_entity_type` table you can see that payments will actually be stored in the `sales_order_entity*` set of tables.

Comment: Yeh thats right so lookup the entity id in sales_order and check the sales_order_entity_*type tables for the data.

Thnx for the explanation clockworkgeek

Comment: Thanks khoekman, that pdf is amazing!
Here's my next [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503759/getting-payment-method-into-report-in-magento) and the original purpose of this question. I am using the dropship module and I'm trying to add the payment method as a column.
With your help and thanks to @clockworkgeek for pointing it out, I was able to locate the table and add it to the collection. Problem is that the fields are populated with nulls. Any idea?